# How can I edit child objects in an MVC4 form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following:

```
@foreach (var parent in Model.Parents)
{      
    @foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    {    
        @Html.TextAreaFor(c => child.name)    
    }                   
}
```

How can I get editing to work for child objects?  I tried something like this as well:

```
<input type="hidden" name="children.Index" value="@child.Id" />
<textarea name="children[@child.Id]" >@child.Name</textarea>
```

To pass an IDictionary to the controller but I get an error:

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
   System.Web.Mvc.CollectionHelpers.ReplaceDictionaryImpl(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEnumerable`1 newContents) +131
```

This seems like a very common task... is there a simple solution to this?  What am I missing?  Do I need to use an Editor Template?  If so, any MVC4-compatible examples would be fantastic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is there a simple solution to this?

Yes.

> What am I missing?

Editor templates.

> Do I need to use an Editor Template?

Yes.

> If so, any MVC4-compatible examples would be fantastic.

ASP.NET MVC 4? Man, editor templates exist since ASP.NET MVC 2. All you need to do is to use them.

So start by getting rid of the outer `foreach` loop and replacing it with:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parents)
```

and then obviously define an editor template that will be rendered automatically for each element of the `Parents` collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Parent.cshtml`):

```
@model Parent
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Children)
```

and then an editor template for each element of the `Children` collection (`~/Views/Shared/Editortemplates/Child.cshtml`) where we will get rid of the inner `foreach` element:

```
@model Child
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.name)
```

everything works by convention in ASP.NET MVC. So in this example I assume that `Parents` is an `IEnumerable<Parent>` and `Children` is an `IEnumerable<Child>`. Adapt the names of your templates accordingly.

Conclusion: everytime you use `foreach` or `for` in an ASP.NET MVC view you are doing it wrong and you should consider getting rid of it and replacing it with an editor/display template.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  I'm using templates now and they rock.  cheers!